# PHP - Moving directories and including certain files

Tags: javascript, php, html, directory

My question to you all is:

This is my current folder structure

> Htdocs
>   ¦   cgi-bin/
>  
>   ¦   error_pages/
>   ¦   includes/
>   ¦   pages/
>   ¦   ssi/
>   ¦   template/

In my template directory I have my header, navbar, index and footer.html files
In my pages directory I have separate folders for all of my seperate web pages in those folders

My current issue is in pages/updates/index.php
I'm trying to include everything from my template directory! I used the following code

```
include("../../template/header.html");<br>
include("../../template/navbar.html");<br>
include("../../template/footer.html");
```

When I do this my content is working but none of my css files and or my java script files will load!

I have tried everything thing from
`include`, `require_once`, `include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/template/header.html';`! I have tried 15 different wesites and this is my last hope!
I don't wanna have to include all of those files into one! I want then dymanic just like they are!

Comment: You have to use full urls for your js/css inculdes or have to set base-href (html head tag) to set the right url like: base-herf is `<base href="http://www.example.com/test/">` and css src like `assets/myjs.js` that will result in `http://www.example.com/test/assets/myjs.js`. To see what going worng you can open via F12 the dev-console in your browser and look at the network tab why css/js is not loaded.

Comment: Thank you so much #JustOnUnderMillions! Now the only problem Im having is http://##############/pages/updates/#introduction                           I can't figure out why #introduction is being injected into my url, I have gone through every bit of code and no where in my code has # introduction

Comment: `#` are normaly for `a`-Tags ancors. So on pageload the page jump directly to the ancor.

Comment: Thank you so much brother! God bless you!